# C# change type of child class in parent(abstract) class

Tags: c#, inheritance

Code:

```
abstract class Parent{
    void changeChild(){

    }
}
class Child1: Parent{
}
class Child2: Parent{
}
//-----
Parent parent = new Child1(); //instantiated as Child1
parent.changeChild(); //change type of this class to Child2
```

so parent should be instance of Child2 class.

I understand that Child1 can be different from Child2(more/less fields, methods), 
but I just want to call constructor on this object, which is not allowed.

simple

```
parent = new Child2();
```

could be done, but there is like 10 child classes(Growing) and I want to move this into parent class

Is this somehow possible in c#?

Thanks

Comment: You certainly want to reconsider using inheritance for that.

Comment: @JacekGorgoń you are right, it can be done without inheritance, it's more effective, nicer, etc..

Comment: And others made nice examples also with generics which I am forced to use in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the type of an existing object, but you can create a new object and return it.

Example:

```
abstract class Parent{

  Parent ChangeChild<T>() where T : Parent {
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(Child1)) {
      return new Child1(this);
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(Child2)) {
      return new Child2(this);
    } else {
      throw new NotImplementedException("Unhandled type");
    }
  }

}

class Child1: Parent{
  public Child1() {} // create
  public Child1(Parent source) {} // convert
}

class Child2: Parent{
  public Child2() {} // create
  public Child2(Parent source) {} // convert
}

Parent parent = new Child1();
parent = parent.ChangeChild<Child2>();
```

Comment: You can simplify this. First add the `new()` constraint to `T`. `Parent ChangeChild<T>() where T : Parent, new()`. Then you can simply create a new child with `new T()`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: Yes, that is an option, but then you can't send the current object to the constructor, so you need an abstract method to populate the object.

Comment: Yes; however this method can be protected and does therefore not influence the public interface of `Parent`. Also the parent needs not to be changed when new derived classes are introduced.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want just that ctor is called automaticcally, should be enough to wtrite something, like

```
class Child1: Child2{
}

class Child2: Parent{
}
```

So you have `Child2` ctor that will be called when `Child1` is constructed. But it's completely different architecture design in regard if yours.

If it's not somethign you're asking for, please clarify.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't fit my project's OOP thinking, example parent=Dog, child1=Husky, child2=whatewer type of dog

Answer (score 0):

Automapper might be your best bet.

```
T changeChild<T>() : Parent{
   // change the type here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
abstract class Parent {
    private Parent Proxy;
    public void ChangeChild<T>() where T : Parent, new() {
        Proxy = new T();
    }
}
```

You'd have to use the `Proxy` object to call members and properties.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it like this. Perhaps you could create `Parent` as a wrapper class

```
class Parent
{
    Parent _child;

    public Parent(Parent child)
    {
        _child = child;
    }

    public void ChangeChild(Parent child)
    {
        _child = child;
    }

    public string AProperty {
        get { return _child.AProperty; }
        set { _child.AProperty = value; }
    }

    public int AMethod(int x)
    {
        return _child.AMethod(x);
    }
}
```

And then

```
Parent parent = new Parent(new Child1());
parent.AProperty = "hello";
int y = parent.AMethod(55);

parent.ChangeChild(new Child2());
```

---

Note: The parent should not have knowledge about the specific children in a good OO-design. This ensures that you can create new children later (say `Child3`) without having to change `Parent`.

However, if this is not an issue for you and you want the parent to care automatically about changing children then change or overload the constructor with

```
    public Parent()
    {
        _child = new Child1();
    }
```

and change or overload `ChangeChild` with

```
    public void ChangeChild()
    {
       if (_child is Child1) {
           _child = new Child2();
       } else {
           _child = new Child1();
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change type of some object in runtime, it's not case for inheritance. You should use composition here. Try something like [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) (if `Parent` class represents some behavior).

```
public class Foo
{
    // provide default value (or inject it via ctor)
    private Parent _parent = new Child1(); 

    public void ChangeChild(Parent parent){
        _parent = parent;
    }

    public void Bar()
    {
        _parent.DoSomething();  
    }
}

public abstract class Parent
{
    public abstract void DoSomething();
}

public class Child1: Parent
{
    public override void DoSomething() { ... }
}

public class Child2: Parent
{
    public override void DoSomething() { ... }
}
```

And now you can change type of dependency at runtime:

```
Foo foo = new Foo(new Child1());
foo.Bar(); // child1 implementation used
foo.ChangeChild(new Child2());
foo.Bar(); // child2 implementation used
```